# Trouble Removing Whitespace in URL (Android Studio)

Tags: android, url, android-studio

So I have a for loop that retrieves a room name to add to my baseurl, and so my URL will be this:

```
a = (baseUrl + roomName + "/users");
```

It works for all the rooms except one, which has a space, so I tried using this:

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

and other attemps but they return this

```
System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://example.com:8443/conferenceRoom/First Floor/users

System.err﹕ at http.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
```

Basically, I have a link like https://example.com:8443/conferenceRoom/First Floor/users

and I want it to be https://example.com:8443/conferenceRoom/FirstFloor/users so no space between 'first' and 'floor'

(note I do use openURLConnection(a) ) when actually using the URL later but I don't think it has anything to pertain to my problem, just wanted to clarify that a is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove whitespaces from your url you can use `trim()` as

```
a= a.trim();
```

If you want to replace whitespaces with "%20" then you can use

```
a = a.replace(" ", "%20");
```

> Having spaces in URLs can cause problems in certain situations. Therefore, a lot of the time spaces are replaced with %20 (which is the ascii encoded value for a space in a URL string). If you remove spaces from your URLs, you won't have the %20s. Otherwise, they're going to stick around.

Comment: for some reason trim was not working, but replace worked for me...thank you!

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept the answer by clicking on the "right mark" just to the left of the answer.

Comment: I just did...was going to a couple minutes ago but it said I had to wait 2 minutes

Comment: Oh okay.Glad you are having a good time here in stackoverflow.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your url might contain UTF whitespaces which are not covered by the \s mofidier.

Just use trim which removes all whitespaces:

```
a = a.trim();
```